# Adding new key to Json array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Below is the json object returned by Mongodb's find query.I wanted to add a new key to the treatmentList array.How can i achieve that using Nodejs?

I have tried treatmentList[0].push({ new Key1: "new Value1"}),but its not working

Actual and expected output is given below -

Actual output

```
[
    {
        "departmentImagepath": "",        
        "treatmentList": [
            {                                
                "shortDescription": "my shortdescription",
                "healingTimeInDays": "8",                
            },
            {
                "shortDescription": "my new shortdescription",
                "healingTimeInDays": "10",     
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Expected output

```
[
    {
        "departmentImagepath": "",        
        "treatmentList": [
            {                                
                "shortDescription": "my shortdescription",
                "healingTimeInDays": "8",  
                 "new Key1": "new value1" //New key to be added
            },
            {
                "shortDescription": "my new shortdescription",
                "healingTimeInDays": "10", 
                 "new Key2": "new value2" //New key to be added
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: `arr[0]["treatmentList"][0]["new Key1"] = "new Value1"`

Comment: somehow its not working...

Comment: @derek `[mcve]` would do it too: [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array#forEach` to iterate through your array and use bracket notation to add new key-value to your object.

```js
const arr = [{"departmentImagepath": "","treatmentList": [{"shortDescription": "my shortdescription","healingTimeInDays": "8",},{"shortDescription": "my new shortdescription","healingTimeInDays": "10",}]}];
arr.forEach(o => o.treatmentList.forEach((ob,i) => ob['new Key'+ (i + 1)] = 'new value' + (i + 1)));
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the json object you get is saved into a variable called `obj`

```
var list = obj[0].treatmentList;
list[0]['new Key1'] = 'new value1';
```